# Javascript - comparing two arrays by specific value and create a new array filled with matches

Tags: javascript, arrays

Please assume I have two arrays filled with objects like this:

```
var arr1 = [{dog: "bark", cat: "meow", cow: "muh"}, {dog: "barking", cat: "meow", cow: "muhing"}]
var arr2 = [{cat: "meow", dog2: "barked"}, {cow: "muhed", savage: "phew", cat: "meowed"}]
```

I wish such output:

```
var arr3 = [{dog: "bark", cat: "meow", cow: "muh", dog2: "barked"}]
```

i.e `arr1` and `arr2`have a common key value pair in some objects, it's `cat: "meow"` and I want these objects merged and pushed into another array, `arr3` in my case. Is it even possible? Thanks in advance!

Comment: can you show one example of correct merge?
What will happen in case of a common key such as `key2`?

Comment: Could you provide those two arrays as how you would like them to be sorted? It's not entirely clear what you want

Comment: lets take the first element of the second array, `key2:val2` is matching with the 1st element as well as the 2nd element of first array, so with whom it will  merge with?

Comment: I updated my question, guys

Comment: @MichaelSpiegelberg are both arrays always going to have the same number of objects?

Comment: @zfrisch unfortunately no, otherwise I could just go through indexes

Answer (score -1):

Please try this:

```
var _ = require('lodash');

var a = [{a:1, b:2}];
var b = [{a:1, b:2, c:3}];

_.merge(a, b);
```

//output: `{a:1, b:2, c:3}`

see if this works for you.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion but it's not what I'm looking for. I don't need to merge all the objects, instead I need to build new objects if specific value eauch of them store is the same.